# Can't get data from fetch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I'm trying to make a fetch call and it works but when I try to get the result from another function I always get undefined.

This is my code:

```
const fetch_output = async (data) => {
await fetch("execute_command", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    //I get the correct response here
    return response
}).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log("Ha habido algún error: ", ex)
})
}

const write_outputs = async () => {
for (const platform_id of platforms_ids) {

    const data = {
        platform_id:platform_id,
        command:command
    }

    await fetch_output(data).then((resp)=>{
        console.log(resp)
        //I get undefined
    })
}
}

write_outputs()
```

I've tried everything but I just don't know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: `fetch_output` doesn't return anything -> `const fetch_output = (data) => fetch(...)`

Comment: It does (I think)
`code`
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    //I get the correct response here
    return response

Comment: Try this `fetch_output =  (data) => await ...` instead of `fetch_output =  (data) => {...})` . better read [ES6 Arrow behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @AngelQuesada it does not. Andreas is correct.

Comment: @prasanth You don't need `async`/`await` for `fetch_output`

Comment: @Andreas yes correct .i just replace the brackets with arrow

Comment: I really need to learn a lot about async/await and promises.
Thank you guys

Comment: This has not really something to do with `async`/`await`/`Promise`s. If you want to pass something from within a function to the caller you just have to `return` that value. And that's all you've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because an async function returns a promise that resolves to the returned value from the function

```
(async () => {})().then(value => console.log("value = ", value)); // undefined
(async () => {return 1})().then(value => console.log("value =" , value)); // 1
```

as you are not returning anything from fetch_output, it resolves to undefined

You should return from the fetch_output function instead of using await.
Also, because fetch is already a promise you can use a normal function instead of an async one

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `await fetch_output()` you should not use `.then()` to retrieve its result. Drop the `await`.

Why? `await` replaces  `function().then().catch()` with `result = await function()` in the way it handles a Promise or an async function. Use `await` or `.then()` but not both.

Comment: That's not true at all... `async/await` is just syntactic sugar around `Promise`s and `.then()`. You can totally mix them: https://jsfiddle.net/wkuqc6xm/